# Issue adding WCF Connected Service on .net Standard

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf, .net-standard-2.0

I am using VS 2017. I created a class library project in .net standard. I then added connected service using a URL (project -> right click -> add -> connected service). When the service is detected, I used default settings and clicked finish.

Unable to generate deps.json, it may have been already generated.  You can specify the "-d" option before the tool name for diagnostic output (for example, "dotnet -d ": C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\GenerateDeps\GenerateDeps.proj

Answer (score 0):

According to your error details, there may by an existed service reference in your project. I suggest you remove the old reference and clean your project. and then add the service reference with Microsoft WCF web service reference provider again.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: There was no reference at all. It was a new project from scratch. I used  dotnet-svcutil instead as I could not figure out the solution. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide

Comment: Do you add the service with microsoft wcf web service reference provider? what is your service metadata address? Are you able to access the service metadata address with the browser?